# C programming, identifier is undefined

Tags: c

Please help me, why is identifier "size3" is undefined?

```
if (size1 > size2)
    {
        int size3 = size1;
    }
    else
    {
        int size3 = size2;
    }

int *array3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * size3);
```

Comment: it's because it's scoped, remove your if and replace by `int size3 = size1 > size2 ? size1 : size2;`

Comment: Because `size3` is declared with `{ ... }` once you leave the `{ ... }` it goes **out of scope** and is no longer able to be accessed (legally). So `size3` has **block scope** (and both your `size3` declarations are in **different blocks**).

Comment: Alternatively, replace all that code with `int *array3 = malloc ((size1 > size2) ? size1 : size2 * sizeof *array3);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you might want to revisit that code snippet you have there

Comment: Umm how so? The ternary is correct as is using the dereferenced size of the `array3` for the type-size. It allocates a block of memory for `array3` as the greater of `size1/size2` times `sizeof *array3` and `array3` is `int*` so `*array3` is `int`.

Comment: Ah, it does compile. My mistake @DavidC.Rankin- your code is correct.

Comment: You can even drop the parens `(...)` around `size1 > size2` if you like `:)` [Simple Example](http://paste.opensuse.org/67484584)

Comment: (size1 > size2) ? size1 : size2 Thank you so much for the help! I'm just a beginner so i don't know much. May i also ask how is ? and : used in here?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'd say you *should* rethink that ternary.  Consider the relative precedence of multiplication and `?:`

Comment: @key `?` and `:` behave as follows.  In a case like `size1 > size2 ? size1 : size2` it first evaluates the term before the `?`  It considers this a simple `TRUE` or `FALSE` value, just like in an `if()` statement.  If it's TRUE it evaluates the term between the `?` and the `:` and that's the result.  If it's FALSE, it evaluates the term after the `:` and that becomes the result.  Note that whichever term it evaluates for the result, it then specifically does not execute the code that would evaluate the other half.  As you will find out, this behavior is extremely useful.

Comment: @dgnuff good catch! You are correct in the *operator precedence*. You need parens around the ternary in that case to prevent `size2 *sizeof *array3` being evaluated before the ternary. E.g. `int *array3 = malloc ((size1 > size2 ? size1 : size2) * sizeof *array3);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must declare the variable (size3) in a scope where it can be accessed. In your case just declare this (int size3;) in outside and before calling if condition. then just assign values. It will solve the problem.

```
int size3 ;
if (size1 > size2)
{
    size3 = size1;
}
else
{
    size3 = size2;
}

int *array3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * size3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the concept of variable scope.
In your code, either the if or the else condition has to get executed. Thus, the line:

```
int size3 = size1
```

or the line

```
int size3 = size2
```

get executed.

These lines mean that you are initializing the `size3` variable. As this is being done inside the if-else block, you have no right to access this variable outside of that block (scope). 
To solve this issue, please define the `size3` variable before the if-else block.

Try this:

```
int size3 = (size1 > size2) ? size1 : size2 
int *array3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * size3);
```

This is the ternery operator. The code looks a lot cleaner.

Another thing to watchout for:
This thing confused me when I was learning c (my first programming language):

```
{ 
    int x = 3;
}

printf("%d", x);
```

This will give you an error

```
 error: 'x' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

The {} initiate a separate code block. The variable x's scope is less than the function (main() for example) and thus gives an undefined error
Hope you found this useful.